# Tracking video events through 'message' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-tracking

I want to track video events through iframe message event but having problems finding documentation on how to do this. I know I need to do something like this window.addEventListener(‘message’, function(message) {
// Check that message.origin is coming from the iframe, and then do stuff with message.data… }); but not sure how I continue from there. I need to track video events that is being exposed like video_start, first_quartile, second_quartile, third_quartile, fourth_quartile and complete.

Any help or direction would be appreciated

this is the code so far

```
$(function() {

    window.addEventListener('message', function(message) {
        if (!(/^https?:\/\/bla.bla.bla..com/).test(message.origin)) {
        return false;
        }
         var data = JSON.parse(message.data);

    switch (message.event) {
        case 'ready':
            onReady();
            break;

        case 'play':
            onPlay(message.data);
            break;

        case 'playProgress':
            onPlayProgress(message.data);
            break;

        case 'pause':
            onPause(message.data);
            break;

        case 'finish':
            onFinish(message.data);
            break;
    }

    function post(action, value) {
    var data = {
      method: action
    };

    if (value) {
        data.value = value;
    }

    var message = JSON.stringify(data);
    player[0].contentWindow.postMessage(message);
}


        function onPlay(data) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Video Played');
            console.log('Video Played');
        }

function onPause(data) {
     ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'Pause', 'Video Paused');
}

function onFinish(data) {
     ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'Finished', 'Video Finished');
}

function onPlayProgress(data) {
    var quartile;
    if (data.percent % 25 === 0) {
        quartile = data.percent / 25;
        ga('Video Progress', {
            quartile: quartile
        })
    }
}


    });

});
```

Comment: they are not the same video is coming from a different url

Comment: the events i want to track are being exposed through the ‘message’ event on the window. I'm trying to console log it but no luck

Comment: yes i think so i need to use something like this window.addEventListener(‘message’, function(message) {
// Check that message.origin is coming from the iframe, and then do stuff with message.data…
});
console log and then send data to GA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163756/discussion-between-joseph-zammit-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: i was hoping i can use this message.data and send to ga

Comment: well i cannot find any documentation to help me with the javascript on how to access the data and send it to GA

Comment: Oh, I've totally misunderstood the question (and removed my comments thus far). You aren't asking how to receive the data, as it is being sent already, you need to know how to "use" the data in some way? something to do with "ga" (whatever that is)

Comment: Yes correct and ga is Google Analytics

Comment: You failed to mention ga in your question. Yet that seems to be the bit you can't do. How about posting the code you do have